# gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I found more details about the bug. 
it seems related with the information, gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart.
after google it, it seems that there is quite limited information about this bug.
Have you ever met this before and know how to solve this?

---

I think it is necessary for me to update what i have found about the crash.

It seems that the crashed described above is not related with subview for that after i disabled all the lines for processing the subview, the crash still happens.

The related code is as follows,

```
{

    float scissor_x = _xMin;
    float scissor_y = _yMin;
    float scissor_w = _xAdd;
    float scissor_h = _yAdd;
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(scissor_x, scissor_y, scissor_w, scissor_h);
    computeXY();//process some computation. 

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    drawImage();//render the result computed above to the screen.

    _xAdd++;
    _yAdd++;

    _xAdd = (_xAdd > 300) ? 100 : _xAdd;
    _yAdd = (_yAdd > 300) ? 100 : _yAdd;

}
```

The lines listed above will be called during each frame. I do not know whether there is some requirements for using glscissor(). If the value of _xAdd, _yAdd, is set as invariable, then the program goes successfully. But, if both of them are changed during each frame, the program is sure to crash after a few steps.

I really puzzled about it.

Here is the output of debugger,

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x7262e, 0x337bc94a    libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-  thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
frame #0: 0x337bc94a libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart + 10
```

Comment: Add exception break point in Xcode to check if any exception generated or else try with Profile->Zombies option to get the exact reason of crash. Let us know if you find anything from it.

Comment: THX. I have tried the profile. But it seems not work on the device, just like frozen.

Comment: Is it freezing, or crashing? That's two different things. If it's crashing, add the crash log. If it's freezing, profile the app (on the device) using instruments and find out where it is spending its time.

Comment: @jrturton. Maybe i expressed it by mistaken. i mean while i try to use the Instruments to profile the program on the device (iPad 3), it seems that the program does not do anything. The current program could be run successfully on iOS simulator. But only on device, it crashed. And also, i could profile the program while using iOS simulator. I have checked some materials that exception breakpoint could not process well with the error info, like this, Thread 1, EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0x1)

Comment: Whats is "SelEdit"? Any third party lib? Looks like application is not able to load some of the component of this lib on device or some issue with server connection. If you can give us more detail.

Comment: i have resubmit my problem here. maybe there is some problem about glscissor(), but i don't know how to use it in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. When gl_scissor() is called, you have to make sure the pixel/texel, taking part in following computation own effective values. So, before i use gl_scissor(), i will initialize all the FBO buffers to make are that all the pixels or texels own effective value.

Thx.